# How to override ASP.NET Core configuration array settings using environment variables

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

**[TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read)**

In an ASP.NET Core app, I have an `appsettings.json` config file which uses a JSON array to configure a collection of settings.

How do I override a setting of one of the array objects using environment variables?

**Background**

I'm using [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) in an ASP.NET Core application and using the [Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--), to allow it to be configured using `appsettings.json`.

The configuration is like this:

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using":  ["Serilog.Sinks.Literate"],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\serilog-configuration-sample.txt" } }
    ],
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId"],
    "Properties": {
        "Application": "Sample"
    }
  }
}
```

When deployed, I want to override some of the settings, e.g. the *MinimumLevel*, and the path to the log file. My preferred option is to do this via environment variables as I'm deploying to an Azure App Service, so I'll use the App settings through the Azure management portal (these are realised as environment variables).

I can easily set the *MinimumLevel* by adding an environment variable with the name: `Serilog:MinimumLevel` and the application name `Serilog:Properties:Application`.

What is the format for specifying a setting with an array?

Comment: I had the same problem - I could not stand the magic of names, colons and array indexes (Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:path) and couple of months ago I wrote a new configuration provider to make this kind of configuration easier - https://github.com/dsbenghe/NotMicrosoft.Configuration

Comment: @Dumitru "Create appsettings.envname.json and repeat the WHOLE!!! Serilog json block again with the new values for MinimumLevel and pathFormat - this is probably the worst thing you can do" - this is not true. You just need to specify settings that change.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

After looking at the configuration in the debugger I found the answer.

- `Serilog__WriteTo__0__Args__path` (All platforms)
- `Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:path` (Windows)
- `Serilog--WriteTo--0--Args--path` (sourced From Azure Key Vault)

> Note: The [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/) documentation now covers this.

So I need to use the array index (zero-based) as if it were a name.

Here is the screenshot of the debugger, also (thanks to [Victor Hurdugaci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149064/victor-hurdugaci) in the comments), the [unit tests](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/tests/Common/ConfigurationBinderTests.Collections.cs#L132-L134) are a good place to look for examples.

[image: configuration in the debugger]

Comment: The tests are another great place to look for examples: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.Test/ConfigurationCollectionBindingTests.cs

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Link is dead. Here's an updated one: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/6cc477ed493e5b0da3c8f609488d667dc65a5576/test/Config.Binder.Test/ConfigurationCollectionBindingTests.cs

Comment: @jaanus-varus Maybe, but the one in the answer is not, as I used a link based on the release tag.

Comment: @JamesSkimming Ah right, I only checked the link in the comment :)

Comment: If you use this environment variable in a unix system, you have to replace the `:` with `__`: `Serilog__WriteTo__0__Args__path`

Comment: The now documentation suggests always using the __ form over the : form, even on Windows.

Comment: Good point @nate-zaugg, I've swapped the answers to make the double underscore prominent.

Comment: is there any way to fully replace array with a brand new array? or it is possible only to overwrite values and/or extended the existing one?

Comment: @Jacob, you should ask that as a new question. It's outside the scope of this question and, there may be several answers which could be worth expanding upon.