# Appending arrays in from appsettings.{Environment}.json to appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings, serilog

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657320/how-to-override-an-asp-net-core-configuration-array-setting-using-environment-va) except its about appending arrays between two different JSON files.

I have an ASP.NET Core application

I have the following in appsettings.Development.Json

```json
"Serilog": {
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "ApplicationInsightsTraces",
      "Args": { "instrumentationKey": "XXXXXXXX" }
    }
  ]
}
```

And in `appsettings.json`:

```json
"Serilog": {
  // . . . Rest of Serilog configs  
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Console",
      "Args": {
      "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {RequestId}-{SourceContext} {$Scope:lj}: {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    },
    "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
  },
}
```

Because Keys overwrite other keys in Appsettings.json I end up with the Console sink being overridden. Is there a syntax to allow it to be appended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to use `WriteTo:1` and make it an object not an array in `appsettings.Development.json` like so:

```json
"Serilog": {
  "WriteTo:1": 
  {
    "Name": "ApplicationInsightsTraces",
    "Args": { "instrumentationKey": "d95066c9-0b17-4e0a-84d4-bb2a4f111016" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good find.  It's touched upon in [JSON configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#json-configuration) documentation, but it's not intuitive especially for arrays.

Comment: @MarkG The unit tests are the best way to figure out how to do weird stuff.

Comment: I have the opposite problem of OP... all my arrays concatenate and I want them to overwrite. I have no idea why everyone else seems to have the opposite experience, but this works for that scenario as well!

Only problem is you can't remove extra elements, so you should have a canary value which indicates the app should ignore an array item (an empty string works for most cases... null values can't be used in appsettings, they're ignored).