# Using named properties for Serilog JSON WriteTo to facilitate environment variable override to disable sink

Tags: .net, configuration, serilog

I'm using a JSON config file with overrides in environment variables. This file includes Serilog configuration, and I'd like to be able to disable a specific sink except under specific conditions using an environment variable override.

I've found that setting environment variables like in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37657321/1102726) to override array elements of of `WriteTo` with a string will effectively disable that sink. For example, I can set the environment variable `Serilog:WriteTo:1` to the string `disable` (or any other string). However, using a named property would make more sense, e.g. `Serilog:WriteTo:SpecialCaseSink`.

Looking at the source code for `ConfigurationReader` (below), it looks like this would work, as it only depends on call `GetChildren` to iterate over the `WriteTo` section, and that's what gets used by `ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions`.

Is there any drawback to this named approach other than the risk of Serilog changing its internal implementation? Is there a different way to selectively enable or disable a Serilog sink that doesn't use indices using just configuration?

Thanks!

```
void ApplySinks(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
{
    var writeToDirective = _section.GetSection("WriteTo");
    if (writeToDirective.GetChildren().Any())
    {
        var methodCalls = GetMethodCalls(writeToDirective);
        CallConfigurationMethods(methodCalls, FindSinkConfigurationMethods(_configurationAssemblies), loggerConfiguration.WriteTo);
    }
}
```

and later

```
internal ILookup<string, Dictionary<string, IConfigurationArgumentValue>> GetMethodCalls(IConfigurationSection directive)
{
    var children = directive.GetChildren().ToList();

    var result =
        (from child in children
            // big query
        );

    return result;
}
```